# how to type in marathi or marathi typing font

Tags: javascript, css

i want to type directly  into textarea marathi not required in english to marathi convert is there any font or solution for this let me know , i have tried so many font but it is english to marathi converted

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family:M-Saras;
        src: url(M-Saras.TTF);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="google_translate_element">
<span id="translateddata">  
     <textarea id="someTextBox"></textarea>
     <div id="target" style="font-family:M-Saras; font-size: 18px"></div>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
    </span>
</div>
<script>
    $('#someTextBox').keyup(function () {
        $('#target').html($(this).val());
    })
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Does it use the same script as any of the Indian languages supported by [Google Noto fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/)?

Comment: try `src: url("M-Saras.TTF");` with quotations, and f12 (developer tools) will show you if it is being loaded

Comment: i think u don't get my quation this program is english to marathi but my requirement is directly type in marathi local language

Comment: I can't understand the reason why so many users, when prompted for clarifications or further details, just type the same question again :_(

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to writing Marathi ,it is devnagri same as hindi or Sanskrit. The following library changes English to devnagri so it suits your need.
Working example : **http://www.quillpad.in/index.html#.WA9Rnuh97IV**
Github repo : **https://github.com/teamtachyon/Quillpad-Server/**

Comment: but how to use it in php can u explain